# Reset PostgreSQL sequence - schema.table.sequence_name

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, sequence

I'm unsure how to reset a sequence in POSTGRESQL with the `ALTER SEQUENCE` function. All documentation only speak of the following syntax (table)_(sequencename)_seq but I keep receiving an error that this relation in any combination I try `relation X does not exist`.

I also tried the following: `schema name.(table)_(sequencename)_seq`.

In the properties of the table under Constraints I see the primary key name is `customers_pkey` and the column related is `id`.

Please find additional context to my initial question:

Below is the excerpt of the Customers table retrieved via the script I'm running. Basically this service retrieved the meta data and data from our production and then ingests it into a Postgresql database (please note that the primary key is of type Binary):

```
('columns before conversion', [[u'id', u'binary(16)', u'NO', u'PRI', None, u''], 
[u'person_id', u'varchar(255)', u'NO', u'', None, u''], [u'ident_id', u'varchar(255)', u'NO', u'', None, u''],[u'seller_id', u'binary(16)', u'YES', u'MUL', None, u''], [u'inserted_at', u'datetime', u'NO', u'', None, u'']])
```

This is the converted metadata to fit POSTGRESQL using sqlalchemy:

```
[OrderedDict([('name', u'id'), ('type_', <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.Unicode'>), ('nullable', False), ('default', None), ('autoincrement', False), ('primary_key', True), ('unique', False)]), OrderedDict([('name', u'person_id'), ('type_', <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.String'>), ('nullable', False), ('default', None), ('autoincrement', False), ('primary_key', False), ('unique', False)]), OrderedDict([('name', u'ident_id'), ('type_', <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.String'>), ('nullable', False), ('default', None), ('autoincrement', False), ('primary_key', False), ('unique', False)]), OrderedDict([('name', u'seller_id'), ('type_', <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.Unicode'>), ('nullable', True), ('default', None), ('autoincrement', False), ('primary_key', False), ('unique', False)]), OrderedDict([('name', u'inserted_at'), ('type_', <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.DateTime'>), ('nullable', False), ('default', None), ('autoincrement', False), ('primary_key', False), ('unique', False)])])
```

The error I'm receiving is:

> (psycopg2.IntegrityError) duplicate key value violates unique
>   constraint "customers_pkey"
>   DETAIL:  Key (id)=(aion}{�}�HQDAS�987) already exists

The error is strange as this table is dropped completely every time the import script runs and then the table is created from scratch automatically.
I was looking to reset the sequence just as a test to check whether somehow even though the table is dropped that the sequence is saved in-memory/cache and that is the reason why the error is raised.

Otherwise I'm at a loss here.

Thanks

Comment: maybe mixed case?.. did you try double quoting the name?.. please don't hide the sequence name - there's no threat in knowing the name of your table

Comment: in psql, use `\ds` to get the actual name of your sequence. Use that name (possibly prefixed with the schema name) in your statement.

Comment: Check ddl of the table, the sequence name will be in columns default

Comment: If it is serial column, then you get sequence name using `pg_get_serial_sequence(table_name, column_name)`. I would guess that name should be `sales.customers_id_seq`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the **exact** statement you are using and the **exact** error message you get and the complete `create table` statement for the table in and sequence in question